# Duplicate Assembly Attributes When Adding NUnit Test Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, nunit

I'm facing an issue while attempting to add an NUnit Test project to my solution.
These are the steps I followed:

1. I created a new ASP.NET Core 6 console application (`ConsoleApp1`).
2. Within the `ConsoleApp1` project, I established a folder named 'Tests'.
3. In the 'Tests' folder, I added an NUnit Test project that's also based on ASP.NET Core 6. This test project is within the same solution as `ConsoleApp1`.  However, when I build the solution, I encounter the following errors:

`Error CS0579: Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyCompanyAttribute' attribute Error CS0579: Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyConfigurationAttribute' attribute Error CS0579: Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyFileVersionAttribute' attribute Error CS0579: Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute' attribute Error CS0579: Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyProductAttribute' attribute Error CS0579: Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyTitleAttribute' attribute Error CS0579: Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute' attribute Error CS0103: The name 'Assert' does not exist in the current context Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'NUnit' could not be found Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SetUp' could not be found Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SetUpAttribute' could not be found Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Test' could not be found Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestAttribute' could not be found`

Could someone please guide me on how to resolve this issue?

I've tried the following steps to troubleshoot:

1. I removed duplicate assembly attributes (`AssemblyCompanyAttribute`, `AssemblyConfigurationAttribute`, etc.) from one of the projects (main console application or NUnit test project).
2. I ensured that the necessary package references are added to the NUnit test project's `.csproj` file:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.3.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.13.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="4.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit.Analyzers" Version="3.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.1.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

3. I included the appropriate using statement in my test class:

```cs
using NUnit.Framework;
```

This is the folder structure of my project.

[image: ```]